# Using system time as UUID

Tags: java, time, uuid

In my application when a user interacts with someone a new notification is added to the other guy's list of notifications. Now I had to a-lot each notification an id.

The catch here is that the Id need only be unique within the scope of the list of notifications for a given user only. Also I don't store beyond 150 notifications.

Now, since I'm anyway saving the time (System.currentTimeMillis()) of each notification, is it safe to reuse this as the id as well ?

It seems highly unlikely that two notifications for the same user could be generated at the same exact time. Eg. multiple people like his post at the same time etc. Even if they do I don't think my server would be servicing each call at the same exact time.

> EDIT

A safe example to consider can be multiple people liking your Facebook post simultaneously and the server adding a unique notification for each event. (keeping the UX aside)

Comment: Why are you against actually using a UUID?

Comment: I want to save space ! By not adding an extra long for id ill save some space on server side :)

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization especially if you are only storing 150 notifications. How many are you expecting to be storing across all users to be worried about this?

Comment: I think that if anybody, then only you as the application developer can estimate how unlikely it is that two notifications will be generated within that time-window.  To me, knowing nothing about your application, it doesn't seem all that unlikely.  Also note that while the precision of `System.currentTimeMillis` is milliseconds, the accuracy can be less fine-grained, making collisions more likely.

Comment: If you want to a use a UUID, you should just use a UUID.

Comment: If multiple people like your face-book post simultaneously can it lead to System.currentTimeMillis collision ?

Comment: There is also a `System.nanoTime` which is far less likely to collide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time is one of the most difficult to handle things in computers. Synchronization across devices is difficult, and even for a single device time may not be strictly monotonic, e.g. due to adjustments to correct clock drift. This may work now, but using time as identifier is going to give you troubles when used at scale, because you will have to handle time-zones etc.

I would prefer using a hash-function to create an identifier in your case. By choosing the hash-function accordingly you can adjust how likely collisions will be, and if you want, you can include the time in the data which is hashed. By hashing over all relevant data, you can ensure that only true duplicates and collisions result in the same value. The advantage of hashing is that it creates a deterministic result everywhere without synchronization.

The second option is choosing one at random, but in that case you need a good source of entropy, and it is often more expensive and less predictable than hashing.

Of course, if the identifier can be chosen by a single entity, a counter is also an option. For multiple parties it would require synchronization and is thus less suitable the large the synchronized group.

Comment: agreed, a hash actually works out better as it will 100% not collide in my case ! :) (until ofc the same person likes your post again :P)

Comment: That depends on what you hash :D

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons why you should still use a uuid. 
First of all because the theory of concurrency issues is that they are always unlikely enough to ever happen. Practice however shows that they do happen quite often.

Also imagine someone trying to find a bug in your software. That person will first of all be really confused about the fact that you just use the system timeand assume that the bug he is hunting will be concurrency related. He's probably gonna spend hours debugging that.

Finally there is no point in saving these few bits. Even if you stored 1 million long values you would use less than 7 mb of space -  which nowadays is even nothing on a phone -  despite a server.

Adding that value will therefore not only improve your applications robustness (and understandability) it will also ensure that you don't end up on thedailywtf.com ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for uuid would be to use `UUID` class and generate the uuid unique code.

But if you are not ok with it, try using `System.nanoTime()` as it is having nanoseconds precision rather than milliseconds in `System.currentTimeMillis`

Comment: nanoTime() doesn't have real precision nanoseconds - but true, isn't worst than milis..

Comment: @JacekCz `System.nanoTime()` would be better anytime